# Jar Rendering Lag

Tags: java, jar, lag

I've just exported my Eclipse project to a runnable jar file. I have no lag issues when I run it in Eclipse, but have extreme lag when running it in the jar. (Running MacOSX 10.9.4)

According to my FPS counter, I'm getting over 900 frames a second, and the game is actually running, but nothing is actually being rendered for a while.

Not sure what code to show because there is a lot of it, as it is an almost completed game. But let me know what code you might need.

Here's my game loop:

```
public void run() {

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    final double numUpdates = 30.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / numUpdates;
    double delta = 0;
    int updates = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(running) {

        long current = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (current - start) / ns;
        start = current;
        if(delta >= 1) {
            update();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Window.frame.setTitle("Rage Mage   UPS: " + updates + ", FPS: " + frames);
            updates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }

    }

}
```

`render()` method:

```
private void render() {
    statusHandler.render(g);      // statusHandler is a class that handles the current state of the game
    Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, null);
}
```

I don't think the game loop is the problem though, because I was getting the same issues before with a different loop, and then I changed to this loop, and nothing has changed.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to do some investigation on your own, remove code until you have the minimum example that show the problem.

Comment: Check if your program succeeds when loading resources. There may be a problem with paths.

Comment: @Raphaël No exceptions are thrown, everything loads fine. It's just lag issues.

Comment: Check if Run configurations in Eclipse (and Eclipse.ini) have special settings, - increased RAM size, different graphics pipeline, etc. Try running your jar with the same settings.

Comment: The project is written in Java 6, so when I run it in Eclipse it runs as Java 6, but when I run the jar, it runs as Java 7 as that is my java version. How can I run the jar as Java 6?

Comment: Regardless of the version and settings, there must be something severely wrong. What does `render()` do exactly?

Comment: **Never call `getGraphics` on a `Component`**. (And if this is not a `Component`, then you once more did not provide enough information - apart from the `statusHandler.render(g)` not being the main unknown part...). Are you using (or trying to use) *active rendering* with an own `BufferStrategy` and such? Otherwise, rendering usually consists of calling `repaint()` and letting Swing to the rest. You won't receive 900 FPS with that, but considering that a monitor has a refresh rate of 60Hz, everything beyond that is useless anyhow...

Comment: @Marco13 I'm not using an own `BufferStrategy`. So, what should I change the method to?

Comment: Try launching your game with Apple's JDK 6. It is a bit faster than Oracle's JDK 7.
Use `export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home` in a terminal to switch to it temporarily.

Comment: @Raphaël What will happen when the OP will decide to distribute his app?

Comment: Assuming that this is a `JComponent`: You should override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. In this method you should first call `super.paintComponent(g)`, and then `statusHandler.render(g)` and `g.drawImage(...)`. The `render()` method should be removed, and in your main loop, you should call `repaint()` instead of `render()`. Also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ and further resources.

Comment: @BackSlash I don't propose this as a definitive solution but only to find what is causing the slow down.

Comment: @Marco13 So I've changed the method, and now am getting about 4-5 million FPS. However, I need to scale the image by three to fit the screen window. How do I do this with the new method?

Comment: It seems there *might* still be something wrong with this FPS count. However, to fill the component with the image, you can just write `g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);`.

Comment: @Marco13 Is `g2` initialised from `getGraphics()`?

Comment: It should be `g.drawImage`, and the `g` is the `g` that you received as a parameter in `paintComponent(Graphics g)  { ... }`

Comment: @Marco13 That's not making a difference, it's still too small

Comment: The image will be as large as the component. If it should be larger, it should probably be painted into the component that *contains* the other component. In any case, there are additional `drawImage` method overloadings that allow you to specify exactly which part of the image should be painted into which part of the component. If this is still an issue, you might consider a new question, preferably including an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - although I'm pretty sure that similar questions have already been answered here.

Comment: @Marco13 I have this line: `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, null);` with `WIDTH` being 266, `HEIGHT` being 200, and `SCALE` being 3. If I remove this line, the image is still being drawn, so it seems this line doesn't actually do anything at all. It actually seems that I only need the `statusHandler.render(g);` line, because with just that it still renders.

Comment: As already said above: You did not provide enough information. Nobody knows what `statusHandler.render(g)` does. If the image still appears, it must be painted somewhere else, how should anybody know that? In any case, the issue seems to be not reproducible, and we should not continue this discussion here in the comments.

Comment: Alright, sorry. I'll post a new question about the scaling issue. Thanks anyway!